# Remove time options in sitecore when selecting time from dropdown list

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7

[image: Time Select Field Example Picture]

When selecting a time from the drop-down list in sitecore the time options are for the whole day.

How do I remove the time that I never select. For example: I want to remove the times from 8pm - 7am so they cannot be selected and the drop down list only shows 8am to 7pm times to select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to the template,

in the child of the template select the **item** that represents the time field,

add a regex in the **validation** field to validate the selected value, and save

if the user select an invalid value, 
an error message will appear to warn

use the **ValidationText** Field to add an error message

Comment: that will just validate the fields, I want to remove them so that when you click to choose the times it only shows a certain range of times not all 24-hours.

Comment: this is the only way i known to do that,
if not, 
you can create a custom filed,look at this article:
http://sitecoreclimber.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/custom-datetime-field/